# Удаление записей

Tags: jquery

Подскажите как можно сделать на jquery удаление diva(записи) с анимацией простейшей,посоветуйте пожалуйста какие нибудь примеры.Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.fadeOut();